# String iterators and understanding a function

Tags: c++, string, iterator

```
bool e_broj(const string &s){
    string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while(it != s.end() && isdigit(*it)){
        ++it;
    }
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

I have  this function to check if a string is a number. I found this snippet online and I would like to understand how it works.

```
// this declares it as the beginning of the string (iterator)
string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); 

// this checks until the end of the string and
// checks if each character of the iterator is a digit?
while(it != s.end() && isdigit(*it)){ 

// this line increases the iterator for next
// character after checking the previous character?
++it;

// this line returns true (is number) if the iterator
// came to the end of the string and the string is empty?
return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? You already seem to have explained the code...

Comment: Just to be clear, you want an explanation of what?  There's already comments explaining select lines of code

Comment: @KerrekSB The question is to help me understand what the code does. Did I explain it correctly, or there is a mistake in my explanation? I'm trying to understand how it works.

Comment: @Huytard Those comments are written by me, I was wondering if I explained well and it works the way I described it or I was wrong?

Comment: You may also be interested in `std::find_if`: `return !s.empty() && s.end() == std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c){return !isdigit(c);});`

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for the reference, I'll take a look.

Comment: Any code passing a `char` to one of the `<cctype>` functions is fragile and bound to cause undefined behavior: `char` is signed on most platforms but these function only accept positive values and `EOF`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the argument to your lambda function shall be of type `unsigned char`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Good point, thanks. Too late to edit :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB This is, of course, an error in the original code as well.  (But it's much easier to write the conversion in the lambda, where the implicit conversion takes care of the job.  Otherwise, you need a `static_cast`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is almost right. The only mistake was at the end:

```
// this line returns true (is number) if the iterator
//  came to the end of the string and the string is empty?
return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
```

This should say "and the string is *not* empty", because the expression is `!s.empty()`, rather than just `s.empty()`.

You may just have worded this funny, but to be clear, the condition on the `while` loop will keep the iterator moving through the string while it's not at the end and while the characters are still digits.

Your terminology with regards to the iterator makes me think you don't quite understand fully what it's doing. You can think of an iterator as being like a pointer (actually, pointers *are* iterators, but not necessarily vice-versa). The first line gives you an iterator that "points at" the first character in the string. Doing `it++` moves the iterator to the next character. `s.end()` gives an iterator that points one past the end of the string (this is a valid iterator). `*it` gives you the character that the iterator is "pointing at".

Answer (score 2):

The while loop stops at the of string OR when a non-digit shows up.

So, if we did not advance all the way to the end (`it != s.end()`), then the string has non-digit and therefore is not a number.

Empty string is a special case: it has no non-digits but it's not a number either.